# C# how to find the value of given coordinate of x,y in two dimension array

Tags: c#-4.0, matrix, coordinates, coordinate-systems, intersect

i'm going to try explain my question again.

I have a matrix like that

```
Int32[,] coordinate = new Int32[5, 5];
```

I'm printing that with thesee codes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(coordinate[i,j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

My question is: When user type "4 2" (there is space between two numbers)
That means user selected the coordinate (4,2) (x,y)
x = 4
y = 2
I need to set a value to coordinate (4,2) in my matrix. My value is -1.
So user typed 4 2 my output should be like that
[intersect of coordinate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFpuu.png)

I need to make it dynamically. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: set: `coordinate[x, y] = value;`  and get: `return coordinate[x, y]`. i didn't understand your question property

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
var s ="4 2";
var res = s.Split(' ');
var x = Int32.Parse(res[0]);
var y = Int32.Parse(res[1]);
cordinate[x,y]=-1;
```

Please not that there is no data validation in this code.

Comment: Hi, firstly thank you for your help. But i dont have problem to get value from user. when i check the matris with coordinate[4,2] it doesnt give me the result. Because arrays are working with index. And indexes start with 0 (zero) but my coordinate starts with 1 (one).  If you can read my question again i think you'll get what i wanted to explain. Thank you.

Comment: As to *"when i check the matris with coordinate[4,2] it doesnt give me the result"*. What does it mean? What result do you receive?

Comment: As to *"And indexes start with 0 (zero) but my coordinate starts with 1 (one)"*. If it is a problem, you can simply substract 1 from coordinates given by a user.